# Outputting data whilst in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have some MVC2 code that loops a collection of type Product held within the view model. Each time I want to output the data I have to use <%: %> along with using <% %>, for example:

```
<% foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsCollection) {
if (item.doesExist == true) { %>
    <%: item.name %>
<% } %>
```

Is there any way to still output item.name without having to close & open tags, e.g. in classic asp we used response.write()?
I appreciate the need to encode data using <%: %>, and am not wanting to bypass this, just wanting to output the encoded data without needing the bracket overhead.

Thanks

Comment: You can still use Response.Write() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Response.Write()` in conjunction with `Html.Encode()`

```
<% foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsCollection) {
  if (item.doesExist == true) {
    Response.Write(Html.Encode(item.name));
  }
} %>
```

Comment: Great!
Does <%: item.name %> pretty much equate to Response.Write(Html.Encode(item.name)?

Comment: Yes, basically <%: %> will encode and output a String object or just output a HtmlString object without encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

Not in aspx view engine, sir.
Check out MVC3  rc2 and @razor view engine.
@razor is the Man.

Comment: Just had a look at @razor, and looks very interesting. Thanks